# Xamarin Android Background Timer Service

Tags: android, service, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In the application I'm developing I need to run a timer between activities to track the duration of an OAuth token. For this purpose I've implemented a Service.

Here's the service code:

```
[return: GeneratedEnum]
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    // Gets the token duration in seconds
    tokenDuration = Convert.ToInt32(intent.GetStringExtra("tokenDuration"));

    tokenStart = Convert.ToDateTime(intent.GetStringExtra("tokenStart"));
    tokenEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(tokenStart.AddSeconds(tokenDuration));
    t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        timer = new Timer(tokenDuration);
        timer.Interval = 60000;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.Enabled = true;

    });
    t.Start();

    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    //return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timeElapsed++;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Minute elapsed,  Total Token duration {0}s, Total time elapsed {1}min", tokenDuration, timeElapsed);


    if (tokenEnd.Add(new TimeSpan(0, -3, 1)) == tokenStart.AddMinutes(timeElapsed))
    {
        timer.Stop();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetAction(action);
        intent.PutExtra("AskRefreshToken", true);
        SendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

My Question regarding this is how can I get the information in an activity when the token requires updating so I can update the viewmodel.
Is there a better way to approach this problem?
Please note that I'm a bit of a beginner in Android development.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for messaging with the messenger plugin. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/Messenger

**Create a special Message**

```
public class TokenRefreshedMessage
    : MvxMessage
{
    public TokenRefreshedMessage(object sender) 
        : base(sender)
    {
    }
}
```

**Publish the Message in your Service**

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Publish(new TokenRefreshedMessage(this));
```

**Subscribe to the Message**

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

    public LocationViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger)
    {
        _token = messenger.Subscribe<TokenRefreshedMessage>(OnTokenRefreshed);
    }

    private void OnTokenRefreshed(TokenRefreshedMessage locationMessage)
    {
        // update properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will check it out later :)